# How do I remove skipped files from output of robocopy?

Tags: robocopy

I have a drive with several TB of data, most of which doesn't change often. When I run robocopy the spew contains reams and reams of skipped files. I'd like to run /L to see what will be copied and what will be deleted before mirroring to my backup drive, but there is so much noise in the log due to the skipped files that sorting through it is time-consuming.

How do I tell robocopy to log only those files that are copied or deleted?

Answer (score 0):

i have found this switch useful to reduce the amount of unnecessary output

```
/ndl    Specifies that directory names are not to be logged.
```

[All robocopy Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)